# Python3.3 Paramiko Windows Install Errors

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, paramiko

Trying to install Paramiko on a Windows XP PC. I am running Python 3.3.1. The enviroment variable is set to C:\Python33\;C

I have PyCrypto installed with no issues.

I have tried Paramiko versions 1.9, 1.10, and master branch version.

I get these errors when I do python setup.py install:

```
C:\temp\paramiko-1.10\paramiko-1.10>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\agent.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\auth_handler.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\ber.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\buffered_pipe.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\channel.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\client.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\common.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\compress.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\config.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\dsskey.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\file.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\hostkeys.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\kex_gex.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\kex_group1.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\logging22.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\message.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\packet.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\pipe.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\pkey.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\primes.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\proxy.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\resource.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\rsakey.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\server.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\sftp.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\sftp_attr.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\sftp_client.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\sftp_file.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\sftp_handle.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\sftp_server.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\sftp_si.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\ssh_exception.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\transport.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\util.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\win_pageant.py -> build\lib\paramiko
copying paramiko\__init__.py -> build\lib\paramiko
running install_lib
byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py to auth_handler.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 311
    except SSHException, e:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py to channel.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 618
    except PipeTimeout, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py to client.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 450
    except SSHException, e:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py to dsskey.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 187
    except BERException, x:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\hostkeys.py to hostkeys.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\hostkeys.py", line 82
    except binascii.Error, e:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_group1.py to kex_group1.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_group1.py", line 35
    P = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC90FDAA22168C234C4C6628B80DC1CD129024E088A67CC74020BBEA63B139B22514A08798E3404DDEF9519B3CD3A431B302B0A6DF25F14374FE1356D6D51C245E485B576625E7EC6F44C42E9A637ED6B0BFF5CB6F406B7EDEE386BFB5A899FA5AE9F24117C4B1FE649286651ECE65381FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL


              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\message.py to message.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\message.py", line 280
    if i > 0xffffffffL:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py to packet.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 97
    self.__sequence_number_out = 0L
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py to pkey.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 307
    except base64.binascii.Error, e:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\proxy.py to proxy.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\proxy.py", line 62
    except IOError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\server.py to server.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\server.py", line 605
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_attr.py to sftp_attr.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_attr.py", line 47
    FLAG_EXTENDED = 0x80000000L
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py to sftp_client.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 88
    except EOFError, x:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.py to sftp_file.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.py", line 467
    except Exception, x:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_handle.py to sftp_handle.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_handle.py", line 103
    except IOError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_server.py to sftp_server.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_server.py", line 95
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py to transport.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 295
    except socket.error, e:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py to util.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 51
    out = 0L
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.10.1-py3.3.egg-info
Writing C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.10.1-py3.3.egg-info
```

Comment: It doesn't look like Paramiko supports Python 3.

Comment: I would like to stay with Python 3...any alternatives for this? Also, would installing the module 6 allow it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paramiko` does not yet support Python3.

Installing `6` would still require some rewriting of the `paramiko` code.

Not sure if either of these support Py3k or suit your needs, but you can try [pushy](http://packages.python.org/pushy/) or [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.1.1/index.html).

Comment: I just went with python 2.7 instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have a full port done that passes all tests on Py2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3. Needs testing. You can find it in pull request #233 on the main github repo.

If someone could test on Windows, that would very helpful. I'm on Mac.